# How to create, save, compile & run a java package including several classes in linux terminal?

Tags: java, ubuntu, terminal

I am new in java programming. I use leafpad for coding & lubuntu linux terminal for compiling & running java files that I create. By now I create several separated .java files each of them including a class & run them successfully. But to creating a package including several related classes I don’t know what I exactly do. How to  create classes? where do save the files? how to compile & run them in terminal?

Comment: Use an IDE. Or prepare to do a **lot** more research.

Comment: Previously I tried to use NetBeans and Geany in my old PC with lubuntu OS. But unfortunately both of them encountered to clash at the step of creating a new project. So I decided to lay away IDEs.